# Android 4.2.2 makes actionbar icon and title clickable as if part of the same button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Before 4.2.2, only the logo was clickable.

As of 4.2.2, the title of the actionbar is clickable along with the logo - **both as if part of the same button**.

You can see an example of this behavior in the Google Reader app - if you have a 4.2.2 device (See screenshot attached).

**How do I disable this behavior and enable clicking only on the icon?** Perhaps it's a bug?

See example code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: Clicking on the logo sets the title to also being clicked]

Comment: Can you provide a reduced test case that demonstrates the problem in code?

Comment: Have you tried hiding the title and using a custom view instead?

Comment: @Charles - added qode snippet to the question. As I said, it behaves differently on 4.2.2 than 4.2.1

Answer (score 3):

This answer seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216966/596531

Haven't tried it out myself because it's a workaround at best and complicates my code, but by hiding the real title it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a bug, that's the normal system behaviour! I reckon they changed it so the users can a bigger clickable target area on that button.

Unless you implement your own ActionBar (maybe by extending ActionBar Sherlock) there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: It is not logical. The title represents the current view. Clicking on it sends the user to the main activity, which was a surprising. If it surprised me, as a developer, it would surprise a lot of users.

Comment: Also, there was no documentation about this in the release notes, which feels more like a bug.

Comment: I'm not here to discuss the logic of it. I'm just telling you that this is the platform new standard behaviour and unless you can convince the guys in Mountain View to change it back, that's how it will be.

Comment: Intentionally or not, how do I return back to the original convention? Why do I think there is nothing I can do about it? Can you reference to the code where separating the icon and the title is not possible?

Comment: You can flash back on your devices an old version of the system. Or you can get the source code, change just this part of it, and re-built 4.2.2 for your device with this change.

Comment: I'm talking about the application as seen by users and want it to be consistent with previous versions. I'm not talking about my device.

Comment: and I'm telling you to either get over it or develop your own action bar!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And (or)

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

That makes the text and the icon clickable with out using

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**except** using the code above here ^^ displays a small arrow next to the icon or text

## EDIT

You could try using this

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And get rid of the action bar text, my guess... but thats not what you want :/ but it makes just the icon clickable