# Add action to Android actionbar title

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I want to have only the title of the app on the ActionBar(AppCompat) and I managed to do that but I'm having a problem with this. On newer versions of Android(>14) when I click the title the drawer appears, so the title is clickable. But on older versions like v11 for example, the title is nonclickable and I have to touch the little drawer icon on the left to show the drawer. Is there any way I can add a custom action to the title, to be clickable and show the drawer layout like on the newer versions?

Answer (score 0):

The below link has the solution for a similar question.. its more like a workaround solution..

[Action Bar icon as up enabled not the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209963/action-bar-icon-as-up-enabled-not-the-title/16216966#16216966)

or

you should create a custom action bar and override the clickable title.. refer the below link to create a custom action bar of your choice..

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/